# Two forms, one submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have two forms, I need one submit button for two forms. How I can do it, without ajax?

```
<form action="" id="form" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="text" name="text">
</form>

<form action="" id="form2" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="text" name="text">
</form>
```

I know that this topic has been raised more than once, but it's not a duplicate, as I need it without ajax

Comment: Do you mean ajax or javascript?

Comment: ajax, because in the architecture of the project it's hard to do

Comment: You can't submit 2 forms at the same time without Ajax, it makes no sense. A form submission means serializing all the inputs (to `x-www-form-urlencoded`, `form-data` or leaving it raw) sending them to the `action` URL using POST or GET, and then doing whatever the server says, either navigating away or immediately rendering a response. How would you do 2 of those at the same time? What is your end goal here and why no Ajax?

Comment: The task is allocated 10 hours, but in addition to this task there are several more. In general, I realized that without Ajax, it's unrealistic to do. I still hoped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**Document.forms**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms) which returns a collection.Thereafter `forms[0]` will return the first form from DOM and so on .Then you can use one button to submit the forms

```
<button type = "button" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>

function submitForm(){
    document.forms[0].submit();
    document.forms[1].submit();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare a `button` and attach a **click** event handler for it.

```
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="submit()" />

function submit(){
   document.getElementById("form1").submit();
   document.getElementById("form2").submit();
}
```

Comment: Is this method not working in conjunction with ajax? Like trigger

Comment: Downvoted because you just copy pasted the solution of the duplicate post.

Comment: Are you talking to me?